# Openshift: databases environment variables are not set in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, openshift, openshift-cartridge, openshift-php-cartidges

I've created a php application on Openshift. Then I added a MySQL database to my app. Afterward I can see database related variables in SSH shell with `env` command.

However when I tried to use environment varibles to setup db connection, it does not retrun them to my php code. As a example:

```
<?php
echo('App: '.$_ENV["OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME"].'<br/>');
echo('Host: '.$_ENV["OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST"]);
```

`OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME` returns Application name correctly however `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST` is null and host information is not available.

I also restarted my application in console.
As a notice I used WinScp to directly upload my application and I'm not sure if deployment of php application needs anything more or less (like some `require` stuff)?

**Update:**

When I checked phpMyAdmin codes, I saw it have a file 'conf.d/passenv.conf' with syntax like this:

```
PassEnv OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT
```

My be it help for resolving my problem.

Comment: `rhc env-list`  (List all the environment variables) 
`rhc env-set {VARIABLE1}={VALUE1} {VARIABLE2}={VALUE2}` (Assign your own...) [Check out this link...](https://blog.openshift.com/taking-advantage-of-environment-variables-in-openshift-php-apps/)  `define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));`

Comment: @zipzit It is supposed that they are defined already when I add new cartridge. Since they might be changes in server configuration and I should not define them manually.

Comment: Oops. Sorry if that was too subtle.  Open RHC, then type `rhc env-list`, and show us what the results are.  Then do a couple of `echo(getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST') );` (as appropriate for environment variables observed from the above env-list)  and use `tail-all` command to see results from your PHP code (if using log files) .  Note: `getenv..` not `$_ENV` (although from what I can tell either should work fine in PHP)

Comment: Question: Did you create your gear with the `PHP, MySQL, and phpMyAdmin` package, or just `PHP` and then later add `MySQL`?

Comment: @zipzit I created php and then add MySQL.

Comment: Were you able to see results of all the environment variables via either  `RHC` or `ssh...` ?

Comment: @zipzit `rhc env-list` needs `-a` param as mandatory option, however ``rhc env-list -a myapp` returns nothing. but according to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1241479 it should be like this as designed!

Comment: Not sure how much time you've already invested, but I'd be very tempted to delete the gear and try the integrated `PHP, MySQL and PhpMyAdmin` package, see if the results are better that way...  Note: that option is only visible from the `PHP (See All)` link on the add a gear page. [Link here..](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_types?tag=php)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117790/discussion-between-vsb-and-zipzit).

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop and start (NOT restart) your application, since you added MySQL after your application was created.
use the rhc app stop and rhc app start commands.